# Bluetooth signal is struggling/interrupting occasionally for all devices

Tags: audio, bluetooth, wireless-headset

I noticed that pretty much all of the bluetooth devices have signal is struggling time to time. The sound becomes crappy for few seconds, bluetooth controllers are lagging and so on. Interruption lasts few seconds but it can happen any time and sometimes it can continue doing so frequently at some period of time.

Is there any way I can diagnose what exactly is causing that? Any help/advice would be appreciable.

Comment: What devices and what kind of distance?  If a computer, can you update the Bluetooth driver?  If a phone, I find the distance is something less than 1.5 meters.

Comment: different devices: TV, controllers, headsets... Distance doesn't matter. Right now I'm sitting at computer and the audio struggles

Comment: Bluetooth is short range so distance matters. But for what you have, try updating the driver.

Comment: if that would be for single device only then I would start by thinking how to fix it. Here it can happen when I connect headset to phone or TV, when controller connects to PS4 or TV connects to bluetooth receiver. It's not related to single device, it is more related to the area and something is blocking or interrupting signal in that area time to time.